# QGIS CRS not set correctly

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, netcdf, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to extract climate variables in QGIS 3.10.2 for sample points with a raster dataset. The raster comes from ClimateNA (https://adaptwest.databasin.org/pages/adaptwest-climatena) and is available as in ASCII grid (.asc) and NetCDF (.nc) formats.

The raster uses the Projection: Lambert Conformal Conic and Datum: D WGS 1984. The best matching CRS seems to be North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic, EPSG:102009

I've set the project CRS to this and verified it for all layers. The raster loads with the CRS undefined and must be set manually, and the sample points, which are actually located in California, are displayed at (0,0). The Google base map appears to be correct.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Another user was able to load it correctly, so hopefully its just a simple step I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: The link you provide says that there is an error in the netCDF proj4 string: "(Please note that there is a typo (an extra hyphen) in the proj4string for the NetCDF files. The value "lon_0=--95.0" should be changed to "lon_0=-95.0")."